# kubectl erroring on interactiveMode must be specified

Tags: kubectl

I ran into an error today with kubectl that wasn't too clear. I'm Using aws-iam-authenticator version 0.5.0

```
_________:~$ kubectl --kubeconfig .kube/config get nodes -n my_nodes
Error in configuration: interactiveMode must be specified for ______ to use exec authentication plugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading aws-iam-authenticator to the latest (0.5.9) fixed it.